# Google Optimize personalization based on DataLayer and LocalStorage

Tags: google-optimize

I'm working on personalization on my website. If users come from the newsletter, the newsletter signup bar should be hidden on the website. I use GTM to check the UTM parameters and create in localStorage and the dataLayer `newsletter: true` to keep track.

In Optimize I've created a Data Layer Variable in the audience targeting (Data Layer Variable Name: `newsletter`). If `newsletter` equals `true` the personalized variant should be shown.
But unfortunately it isn't (only base variant is shown).
I've already checked in Chrome Dev Tools > Console if the dataLayer contains the newsletter, which it does.
[image: DataLayer]

Additionally I've tried to show the Optimize version of the website based on the value from LocalStorage. For that I've created a JavaScript Variable in Optimize and named it `newsletter` (same as in localStorage) which has to equal `true` too; but this doesn't work either.

If it helps to solve the issue: The installation diagnostics in Google Optimize shows a popup saying the Analytics tracking code was not found, although the Google Tag Assistant in Chrome shows GA, Optimize and GTM as working.